# delete broken network shortcuts from My Network Places

Tags: networking, windows-xp, windows-explorer

I am running Windows XP SP3.

I have several shortcuts in My Network Places in Explorer that point to nonexistent IP addresses.  I never succeed to delete them. When I do left-click on them, or right-click, Explorer goes into unresponsive state for a very long time. No matter what mouse gestures I try, it is unresponsive, not allowing me to delete them.

What is the solution to delete these broken network shortcuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried left-clicking them and then hitting the "delete" key on your keyboard?

Comment: Yes it works, if I give t enough time. I was confused by the long timeout during which Explorer is unresponsive. Thanks.